# cv2.putText, fillConvexPoly and circle return "positional argument follows keyword argument"

Tags: python, opencv

I need to write on my webcam. I am using openCV in Python. Ive tested putText, fillConvexPoly and circle each return the error "positional argument follows keyword argument" but the lines method (`cv2.line`) works fine. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
import cv2
import random

cv2.namedWindow("preview")
vc = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

if vc.isOpened(): # try to get the first frame
    rval, frame = vc.read()
else:
    rval = False

while rval:

    cv2.imshow("preview", frame)
    rval, frame = vc.read()
    key = cv2.waitKey(20)
    if key == 27: # hit Esc to close
        break
    else:
        cv2.fillConvexPoly(img=frame, pt1=(300, 300), pt2=(random.randint(0,600), random.randint(0,600)), pt3 = (20,20), pt4 = (random.randint(0,600),random.randint(0,600) ), color, lineType = 8, shift=0)
        cv2.putText(img, 'Good job Self!', (230, 50), font, 0.8, (0, 255, 0), 2, cv.LINE_AA)

vc.release()
cv2.destroyWindow("preview")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare points as a numpy array, the `cv2.fillConvexPoly` only accept 5 parameters. And pressing key to exit need to be during `cv2.waitKey` or else you cannot stop capturing.

Try it out.

```
import cv2
import random
import numpy as np

cv2.namedWindow("preview")
vc = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

if vc.isOpened(): # try to get the first frame
    rval, frame = vc.read()
else:
    rval = False

while rval:

    cv2.imshow("preview", frame)
    rval, frame = vc.read()
    if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord('q'):#hit q to close
        break
    else:
        pts = np.array(((300,300), 
                        (random.randint(0,600), random.randint(0,600)),
                        (20,20),
                        (random.randint(0,600),random.randint(0,600))), dtype=int)
        cv2.fillConvexPoly(frame, pts, (255,0,0),8, 0)
        cv2.putText(frame, 'Good job Self!', (230, 50), font, 0.8, (0, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

vc.release()
cv2.destroyWindow("preview")
```

Comment: From deep in my baby programmer heart... I thank you!